# A curve is regular if and only if its veloctiy vector is not equal to 0

Tags: differential-geometry

I am starting to learn about Differential Geometry. I am using "Elements of Differential Geometry" by Richard S. Millman and George D. Parker (I have very little background knowledge on the subject). Anyways, in one of the definitions of the book it states that a regular curve in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is a function $\alpha:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ which is of class $C^k$ for some $k\geq 1$ and for which $d\alpha/dt\neq 0$ for all $t\in (a,b)$. My questions are

1. Would the function $\alpha(t)=(\frac{1}{t^3},\frac{1}{t^2},0)$ be regular on $\mathbb{R}^3$?
2. On one of the examples the book states that a curve is regular if and only if the velocity vecotor is not equal to 0. Does this follow naturally from the definition, or is there a proof that can be filled to show this? If so, what would be such proof (or exercise)?

Comment: For 1: what is the derivative of that Curve? Does it vanish?

Comment: That's what I am wondering. Technically, $\infty$ is not part of $\mathbb{R}$. If $0$ "equals" $1/\infty$, wouldn't that imply that $\alpha (t)$ is regular on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Huh? No, infinity is not a real  number, there is absolutely no need to even think about it.

Comment: So it is possible to obtain 0 with $\frac{1}{t^3}$ and $\frac{1}{t^4}$ without having $\infty$?

Comment: Suppose $t$ is a real number such that $1/t^3=0$... What can you say about $t$?

Comment: ...$t$ is not a real number? $t>1$? I don't know

Comment: What happens if you multiply $1/t^3$ by $t^4$?

Comment: You would get $t$

Comment: And if $1/t^3$ is zero, what can you conclude about $t$?

Comment: How do you define $\rho = 0$?

Comment: I am not sure how this differs from your question of suppose $t$ is a real number such that $1/t^3=0$..

Comment: It is the same question. I am trying to walk you down towards the answer.

Comment: As an element of $\mathbb{R}$, I believe that some people say that any real number divided by infinity is $0$ as well as any number multiplied by 0 is 0.

Comment: In any case, I don't know why you are starting out with differential geometry of curves and surfaces, but I am quite sure that you need a firm grasp of calculus and basic algebra to do that. Maybe your time would be better spent trying to get that?

Comment: As I told you, infinity is not a number, you cannott divide, multiply, add or substract infinity to anything, as it simply does not make any sense. (And please oh please no one come bringing up completed reals or whatnot which are as relevant to this discussion as Sobolev's inequalities....)

Comment: Then, would you be kind enough to give the answer before dismissing me to calculus or algebra?

Comment: No, I do not think it would do any good. And, please, notice that I am not dismissing you to anything: my suggestion is intended to help you avoid the pain of stating out with something for which you do not seem to be prepared.

Comment: Then, there's no reason for me to trust anything you said...

Comment: You are free not to believe me.

Comment: I see. I apologize then. Which books would you then recommend?

Comment: If $\rho \neq 0$, the curve is regular, otherwise we need more information when it is $0$, actually if it is $0$, there is a good chance that it will no longer be smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this curve is regular for all real values of $t$ except at $t=0$ because the derivative is not defined.
The second follows naturally from definition.

Comment: The curve cannot be regular or not regular at $t=0$ for he simple reason **that it is not defined at $t=0$**.